# connecting Docker on Windows to Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: windows, docker, ssh-keys, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to follow this https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce
tutorial on Windows 10 but I am receiving an SSH key error. I've tried various modifications on the file's permissions using both Cygwin chmod and the Windows properties GUI but I am unable to get rid of this error, even after removing all permissions from other users. How can I fix this?

```
docker run -it -p "8081:8080" -v "/C/Users/***/Documents/:/content" -e "GATEWAY_VM=spheric-basis-
148416/us-east1-b/lala123" gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
Updated property [core/project].
Updated property [compute/zone].
Will connect to the kernel gateway running on the GCE VM lala123 as ****
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.7788356429671748568' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/content/datalab/.config/.ssh/google_compute_engine' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
key_load_private_type: bad permissions
```

Comment: Do you want to see or show the file permissions of the respective directory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

Your private key files should have stricter permissions. Try setting `chmod 600` on your keys under `.ssh`.